# DeepLearning Anomaly Detection for images

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I am still relatively new to the world of Deep Learning. I wanted to create a Deep Learning model (preferably using Tensorflow/Keras) for image anomaly detection. By anomaly detection I mean, essentially a `OneClassSVM`.

I have already tried sklearn's OneClassSVM using HOG features from the image. I was wondering if there is some example of how I can do this in deep learning. I looked up but couldn't find one single code piece that handles this case.

Comment: Using HOG is a method of feature engineering. Usually in deep learning you don't deal with that, you let your model figure that out for you, that's why you most likely won't find very similar examples. So if you want to try deep learning, you should try a standard convolutional network with simply the images as input instead of pre extracted features.

Comment: Thanks @maz. Yep agreed. Can you point me to a good example of this doing single class classification in tensorflow? I have spent a bunch of time looking into this but still have come up empty handed.

Comment: You could use an example for multi class classification with two changes: First, change your last activation for either a sigmoid or a tanh (do not use softmax for a single class, it will not work). Second, change the last Dense layer so it will have a single output (in keras this is done with Dense(1)). I don't know single class examples, but with these two changes you could try this mnist cnn example from keras https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py. Just watch out for the differences between keras 2 and 1 (mostly name changes).

Comment: thanks @maz let me try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way of doing this in Keras is with the [KerasRegressor](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/) wrapper module (they wrap sci-kit learn's regressor interface). Useful information can also be found in the [source](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py) code of that module. Basically you first have to define your Network Model, for example:

```py
def simple_model():
    #Input layer
    data_in = Input(shape=(13,)) 
    #First layer, fully connected, ReLU activation
    layer_1 = Dense(13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='normal')(data_in)   
    #second layer...etc
    layer_2 = Dense(6,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='normal')(layer_1)  
    #Output, single node without activation
    data_out = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal')(layer_2)     
    #Save and Compile model
    model = Model(inputs=data_in, outputs=data_out)   
    #you may choose any loss or optimizer function, be careful which you chose 
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

Then, pass it to the `KerasRegressor` builder and `fit` with your data:

```py
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
#chose your epochs and batches 
regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn=simple_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=64)
#fit with your data
regressor.fit(data, labels, epochs=100)
```

For which you can now do predictions or obtain its score:

```py
p = regressor.predict(data_test) #obtain predicted value
score = regressor.score(data_test, labels_test) #obtain test score
```

---

In your case, as you need to detect anomalous images from the ones that are ok, *one approach* you can take is to train your regressor by passing anomalous images labeled `1` and images that are ok labeled `0`.

This will make your model to return a value closer to 1 when the input is an anomalous image, enabling you to *threshold* the desired results. You can think of this output as its R^2 coefficient to the "Anomalous Model" you trained as 1 (perfect match).

Also, as you mentioned, Autoencoders are another way to do anomaly detection. For this I suggest you take a look at the Keras Blog post [Building Autoencoders in Keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html), where they explain in detail about the implementation of them with the Keras library.

---

It is worth noticing that Single-class classification is another way of saying Regression.

Classification tries to find a *probability distribution* among the `N` possible classes, and you usually pick the most probable class as the output (that is why most Classification Networks use `Sigmoid` activation on their output labels, as it has range [0, 1]). Its *output is discrete/categorical*.

Similarly, Regression tries to find the *best model that represents your data*, by minimizing the error or some other metric (like the well-known R^2 metric, or [Coefficient of Determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)). Its *output is a real number/continuous* (and the reason why most Regression Networks don't use activations on their outputs). I hope this helps, good luck with your coding.

Comment: Can this wrapped model be saved as a .pb graph? I am looking to implement this in c# but cannot due to no sklearn in port in c#.

Comment: I am not sure Jodh. But perhaps it is possible to study the format that this model is saved and convert it somehow to this .pb format you mention